# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException with custom getter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting this exception when I enable the custom-getter.
and when I comment it I don't get the exception.

I need this getter to generate the transiaent value `'state'` that is calculated from another persisted value, it is the complete description of the other persisted version `'stateId'`

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: 1; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 1 (through reference chain: com.example.model.Employee["state"])]
```

this is my entity class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = UUIDGenerator.UUID_GEN_STRATEGY ) //strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    UUID id ;
    @Column
    String name;
    @Column
    String telephone;
    @Column
    String address;

    @Enumerated
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="state", nullable = false)
    State stateId;

    @Transient
    List<String> state;

    public Employee(BaseEmployeeRequest employee) {
        stateId = State.ADDED;
        this.name = employee.getName();
        this.address = employee.getAddress();
        this.telephone = employee.getTelephone();
    }

    public void setState(List<String> state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public List<String> getState(){
        List<String> state = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(stateId !=null) {
            String[] states = stateId.getId().split("_");
            if(states[1] ==null || states[1].length()==0){
                state.add(states[0]);
                state.add(EventFullName.SECURITY.get(states[1]));
                state.add(EventFullName.SECURITY.get(states[2]));
            }
            return state;
        }
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared @Data from Lombok already, Which has a getter and setter inside, so when you write them manually, it becomes a duplicate.

You can read from [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-data-annotation-in-lombok): `@Data` annotation is equivalent to the combination of the following annotations:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
```

If you want to use setter or getter from different place, just use as same you will use when you create manually, it will show up

For example:

```
public class Work{
public static void main(String[] args){
   Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setName("John");
    String name = emp.getName(); // => John
    
  }
}
```

As you see from example, you don't need to set them manually, Lombok `@Data` will do for you